# Rejecting a model in favor of another

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hypothesis-testing, model-comparison

Let's say currently there is a specific time series forecasting model A in use for some case and I want to test and prove whether another model B is significantly better and should replace model A.

What will be the way to do that statistically? I thought of getting both models MSE and then check if the difference is significant but I saw somewhere that this will work when I need just to choose a model and not try and reject one for another.

Answer (score 1):

The 'best' way to chose your final model would to compare some goodness of fit statistic based on a holdout sample. For example, if the MSE for model A is materially better than it is for model B, you'd chose model A as your final model. However, if there's no material difference, I'd chose the model that's easiest to interpret and makes the most sense.

If the model A is nested within model B (or vice versa), and the likelihood exists, you could have a look at using a [likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test). This will give you a more concrete framework for choosing one model over the other.

Comment: And how can I be sure the difference is material? Is there some statistical test to justify that?

Comment: Choosing the 'best' model is a bit of an art. There's no hard and fast rule or statistical test. In general, model selection should be based on a combination of subject matter knowledge and goodness of fit statistics. Back to your example - say model A is an ARIMA (MSE = 1.4) and model B is a LSTM network (MSE = 1.3). Model B is much more complex compared to model A, and only gives slightly better performance. For that reason, I'd chose model A over model B. If you wanted some sort of empirical cut-off, you could chose model A over model B whenever the MSE is 10% smaller (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a holdout set then your stat test will either say model a is significantly better than model b or not.  If it's significantly better then it just agrees with your holdout test. But if it's not 'significantly' better then how would you choose your model?  You would probably just use the holdout set accuracy.  So there isn't much use in the statistical test unless you want to know if changing the model is worth the effort like if it has to be switched into production.

Either way, I would just use the holdout accuracy and set a threshold for % increase in accuracy of the holdout set as a 'test'.

Comment: The case here is that there is one model in use. That's why I want some assurance that the alternative model is not only slightly better, so it will be worth the transition.

Comment: Yep, so I would attempt to equate accuracy back to some dollar amount. For example an increase of performance of 10% would decrease the cost of holding inventory by 5 million.  That would help you make your final decision, if the accuracy gain isn't worth the hours to change models for production then don't do it.  Alternatively, if you just want to tell people that your model is better with high confidence then you could do more rigorous cross validation: https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html .